# I am Creating Xamarin and i try to Convert Array in to String But i can not able to convert Array into the String

Tags: c#, xamarin

[image: Please click here for image]

I get the value in the array but I can not able to convert it to a string,
and in the variable, I get this "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]".

```cs
ValidatorFunc = (arg) =>
{
    var result = string.Join("",  arg);
    return true;
};
```

When I use the `if` condition it works properly

```cs
var args = Application.Current.Properties["pincode"] as string;

ValidatorFunc = (arg) =>
{
    // var x = String.Join("", arg);
    if (String.Join("", arg) == args)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I don't see any error in `string.Join`.. Check this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kfz4ca.

Comment: What framework version are you on? What overloads of `String.Join` do you see?

Comment: A `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad However it is not a `List<char>`.

Comment: @Renish Any update for this case?

Comment: I am using "IEnumerable<char>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `IEnumerable<char>` make a code sample for you. Please check it.

[image]

Code:

```
 string str = "8080";

        IEnumerable<char> args = str.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x));

        string result = string.Join("", args);
        if (String.Join("", args) == str)
        {

        }
```

Output:

[image]